# How to create JFrame from another main class as separate thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe, program-entry-point

I want to create one Jframe from another class (main class) and then I want to display Jframe only if no error in main method. Otherwise I want to create & display dialog by passing that same jframe.
I forgot thread concept anywhere give me the solution, I tried below code, that prints "abcde" but not display the frame program complete.

Note : there is no main method in JFrame od ErrorDialog. They are just custom container.

```
public class Start{

    public static Main mf=null;

    public static void main(String args[]){

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mf = new Main();
            }
        });
        try {
            // Some extra code
            System.out.println("abcde");     //  this is print and then program complete
            mf.setVisible(true);            //   this line will not run
        } catch (Exception e) {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new ErrorDialog(mf, true).setVisible(true);;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Is your question *"How to X?"*?  If so, add it as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37382278/edit).  If not, think of a specific question and do the same (edit).

Comment: The key concept you seem to be misunderstanding is the meaning of "later"

Answer (score 1):

Try my suggestion its working..

Just use `invokeAndWait()` method insted of using `invokeLater()` method.
Because `invokeLater()` method create `NullpointerException`.
But `invokeAndWait()` must be inside `try-catch` block.

`try {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mf = new Main();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }`